# prolog find minimum fact with two conditions

Tags: prolog

I'm working on educational project about Prolog, but I haven't found a solution on this problem.

I have a list of facts like these:

```
car(1,1,1).
car(2,2,2).
car(3,1,2).
car(4,2,3).
```

What I have to do is to **take the fact where the second parameter is maximum**, and, **if exists two facts with the second parameter equal, take the fact where the second parameter is maximum and the third parameter is minimum**.
For example, in the list of facts, I would be to select `car(2,2,2)` because it has the maximum value of the second parameter, and the minimum of the third.

I have tried many times, but I don't know how to proceed.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: In a FOL [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(logic)): `∃ (A,B,C): (car(A,B,C) ⋀ ∀ (A2,B2,C2): (car(A2,B2,C2) ⇒ B ≥ B2) ⋀ ∀ (A3,B3,C3): (car(A3,B,C3) ⇒ C ≤ C3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward solution. Find the max second parameter and min third parameter with second as required.

```
req(car(A, B, C)) :-
    findall(X, car(_, X, _), Xs),
    max_list(Xs, B),
    findall(Y, car(_, B, Y), Ys),
    min_list(Ys, C),
    car(A, B, C).
```

```
?- req(Car).
Car = car(2, 2, 2)
```